# Pass Common block array size to subroutine in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I would like to pass the array dimension as a dummy variable to a subroutine. The array itself is on a common block. Here is the code:

```
PROGRAM test
integer i, nn
integer PARAMETER(Nt=10)
real x(Nt), y(nt), z(Nt)
Common /Bdat/ z
nn=Nt
do i=1,Nt
x(i)=i+1
z(i)=i-1
enddo
call estimate(x,y,nn)
print*, y
return
end

subroutine estimate(x,y,jj)
integer i,jj
real x(jj), y(jj), zq(jj)
COMMON /Bdat/ zq
do i=1, jj
y(i)=x(i)+zq(i)
enddo
return
end
```

this is the error I get from the subroutine:

```
real x(jj), y(jj), zq(jj)
                      1
```

Error: Variable 'jj' at (1) in this context must be constant

I would really appreciate it if anybody could solve the issue.

Comment: It is possible to give a meaningful answer to the question, but would you contemplate an answer which says: don't use common blocks for this purpose?  Fortran has moved on an awful lot in the last 30 years.

Comment: I don't think anybody in their right mind should use Fortran when Python and MATLAB are around. There are some old codes out there that people have to revisit every now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope problem. Read: [Scope in Fortran](http://www.inscc.utah.edu/~krueger/6150/Scope_Fortran_90.pdf). That is, your subroutine `estimate` needs access to the variable `Nt` which you need to pass as an additional argument, or you can move the entire subroutine inside your program using the `contains` statement.  This will allow your program to run successfully, but I highly encourage you to abstain from using `common` blocks. If you cannot avoid them due to legacy codes see: [Improve your FORTRAN 77 programs using some Fortran 90 features](http://iprc.soest.hawaii.edu/users/furue/improve-fortran.html)

Try using modules instead:

```
    module bdat

      implicit none

      private
      public :: NT, z

      integer, parameter :: NT = 10
      real               :: z(NT) 

    end module bdat

    module my_sub

      use bdat, only: &
           zq => z ! You're free to rename the variable

      implicit none
      private
      public :: estimate

    contains

      subroutine estimate(x,y)
        ! calling arguments
        real, intent (in) :: x(:)
        real, intent (out) :: y(:)

        ! local variables
        integer :: i, jj

        jj = size(x)

        do i=1, jj
           y(i)=x(i)+zq(i)
        end do

      end subroutine estimate

    end module my_sub

    program test

      use bdat, only: &
           NT, z

      use my_sub, only: &
           estimate

      implicit none

      integer :: i
      real :: x(NT), y(NT)

      do i=1,NT
         x(i)=i+1
         z(i)=i-1
      end do

      call estimate(x,y)

      print *, y

    end program test
```

Comment: What if x, y, or z arrays have to be read from an input file and be made available to multiple subroutines. Fortran doesn't allow for open and read statements in a module.

Comment: That is not true! Open and read statements are allowed inside subroutines with are all enclosed inside modules. I suggest you put the arrays inside derived data types which eliminates the need to share global variables among subroutines.